# Aliasing through unions

Tags: c, unions, strict-aliasing, type-punning

The `6.5(p7)` has a bullet about `union`s and `aggregate`s:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> [...]
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>   types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or

This is not quite clear what it means. Does it require at *least one member* or *all members* to satisfy the strict aliasing rule. Particularly about `union`s:

```
union aliased{
    unsigned char uint64_repr[sizeof(uint64_t)];
    uint64_t value;
};

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    uint64_t some_random_value = 123;
    union aliased alias;
    memcpy(&(alias.uint64_repr), &some_random_value, sizeof(uint64_t));
    printf("Value = %" PRIu64 "\n", alias.value);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f82ff7ec75a303a)

Is the behavior of the program well-defined? If no, what does the bullet mean?

Comment: Not related to your question but If uint64_repr is supposed to represent the bytes of uint64_t use ”unsigned char”, not ”char”.

Comment: @Fredrik Sure, thanks.

Comment: The program is OK (although you don't need `&()`). As for the exact meaning, gotta unpack the language somehow...

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thanks. But I have some question. Is it common to use `union` for type-punning? I mean if we have a stack-allocated object with some declared type in order to reinterpret it as another type _in a conforming way_ we have to define a union containing the two and use it to access this object.

Comment: Type punning (in either form) is quite common in low-level code that deals with a variety of types (compilers/interpreters/JITs, OSes, protocols). In C there are two general ways (other than accessing unsigned as signed and vice versa): `memcpy()` and `union`. In C++ of those two there's just `memcpy()`.

Comment: `The New C Standard: An Economic and Cultural Commentary` says of `— an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)`: `A particular object may be an element of an array or a member of a structure or union type. Objects having one of these derived types can be accessed as a whole; for instance, using an assignment operator (the array object will need to be a member of a structure or union type). It is this access as a whole that in turn accesses the stored value(s) of the members`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: The Standard defines the meaning of `someUnion.someArray[index]` as being equivalent to `*(someUnion.someArray+index)`.  Neither clang nor gcc will reliably recognize the latter form as being an access to `someUnion`.  Does the Standard make any distinction between the forms, require compilers to recognize the second, or rely upon compilers to recognize patterns beyond what it actually requires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is means is using a `union` is one of the standard compliant ways to avoid type punning and the strict aliasing violation that would otherwise occur if you attempted to access a stored value through a pointer of a different type.

Take for example `unsigned` and `float`, generally both 32-bits and in certain cases looking at the stored value from either `unsigned*` or `float*` may be needed. You cannot for example do:

```
    float f = 3.3;
    // unsigned u = *(unsigned *)&f;  /* violation */
```

Following [6.5(p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) you can use a `union` between both types and access the same information as either `unsigned` or `float` without type-punning a pointer or running afoul of the strict aliasing rule, e.g.

```
typedef union {
    float f;
    unsigned u;
} f2u;
...    
    float f = 3.3;
    // unsigned u = *(unsigned *)&f;  /* violation */
    f2u fu = { .f = f };
    unsigned u = fu.u;                /* OK - no violation */
```

So the strict aliasing rule prevents accessing memory with an effective-type through a pointer of another type, unless that pointer is `char` type or a pointer to a member of a union between the two types.

(**note:** that section of the standard is one that is anything but an example of clarity. (you can read it 10 times and still scratch your head) Its intent is to curb the abuse of pointer types, while still recognizing that a block of memory in any form must be capable of being accessed through a character type, (and a `union` is among the other allowable manners of access).)

Compilers have gotten much better in the past few years at flagging violations of the rule.

Comment: Thanks for shedding the light about aliasing through `union`s. But they mentioned _an aggregate or union type_. Can we modify your example as `typedef struct { float f; unsigned u;} f2s;` to be used for aliasing purpose?

Comment: What you are doing with the `union` and the same in my example, is simply allowing the bytes in memory (which are the same when the union has a value) to be treated as having either an effective type of `float` or `unsigned` and the compiler not having problems. So yes, you can rename it `myfloat2unsigned` or anything you like.

Comment: So what is the answer to the question? Is the behavior of the program well-defined? (I guess yes, but please clarify)

Comment: Yes, the answer is the code is well defined. There are a number of cases where you are simply 'looking at data' through another type (or through another window if that analogy helps). Using a pointer to view data of another, while technically a violation, depending on how it is done, rarely has any consequences. It is using a pointer of a different type to attempt to modify where you see the greatest risk of corruption/undefined behavior due to type-size or padding mismatches. It's not worth tempting fate in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

The bullet point serves two purposes.  First of all, if one recognizes that an access to an lvalue which is, or might be, visibly based upon an lvalue of a particular type should be recognized as an lvalue, or possible lvalue, of the latter type, then given something like:

```
union U {int x[10]; float y[10];} u;
```

an lvalue which is visibly derived from `u` would be allowed to access all of the objects contained therein.  The range of situations in which an implementation would recognize that an lvalue is based upon another is a quality-of-implementation issue, with some quality compilers like icc being able to recognize, given something like:

```
int load_array_element(int *array, int i) { return array[i]); }
...
int test(int i) { return load_array_element(&u.x, i); }
```

that anything that *particular* call to `load_array_element` might do with `*array` would done with `u` (it is being given an address of an lvalue directly formed from `u`, after all), and other compilers like clang and gcc being unable to recognize even a construct like `*(u.x+i)` as an lvalue based on `u`.

A second purpose of the bullet is to suggest that even if a compiler is too primitive to keep track of lvalue derivation in straight-line code, it should recognize that given declarations:

```
int *p,i;
struct foo { int x;} foo;
```

if it sees `*p=1; i=foo.x;` without having paid any attention to where `p` came from, it must ensure that the write to `*p` is performed before the read of `foo.x`.  Even if that should only really be necessary in cases where a compiler which had been bothering to pay attention would have been able to see that `p` had been formed from `foo`, describing things in those terms would have increased apparent compiler complexity compared with making the access to `foo.x` force the completion of any pending writes to the targets of integer pointers.

Note that if one is interested only in cases where a struct or union member is accessed via freshly-derived pointer, there's no need to include a general permission to access the struct or union object via lvalue of member type.  Given the code sequence: `foo.x = 1; p = &foo.x; i=*p;`, the act of taking the address of `foo.x` should cause the compiler to complete any pending writes to `foo.x` before running any code that might use the address (a compiler that has no idea what downstream code would do with the address could simply complete the write immediately).  If the code sequence were `foo.x = 1; i = *p;`, the act of accessing `foo.x` via the lvalue `foo` would mean that any existing pointer that might identify that storage would be "stale", and thus a compiler would be under no obligation to recognize that such a pointer might identify the same storage as `foo.x`.

Note that despite footnote 88 which clearly says that the purpose of the "strict aliasing rule" is to specify when objects are allowed to alias, the interpretation by gcc and clang interpret the rule as an excuse to ignore cases in which objects are accessed by lvalues which are quite visibly derived from them.  Perhaps in retrospect the authors of the Standard should have included a provision "Note that this rule makes no attempt to forbid low-quality compilers from behaving in obtuse fashion, but is not intended to invite such behavior" but the authors of C89 had no reason to expect that the rule would be interpreted as it has, and the authors of clang and gcc would almost certainly veto any suggestion to add such language now.